# user.is_authenticated not working on production

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.11.5 version and in my template `{{ user.is_authenticated }}` is printing `CallableBool(False)` or `CallableBool(True)`

Which is confusing my this template condition

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26988 I have seen this issue on django project website and it was saying to upgrade to django version 1.10 but my django version is 1.11.5

My python version is 3.5
I think instead of bool value true or false i am getting CallableBool which is type and is confusing my condition `user.is_authenticated`

views.py

```
class LandingView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "website/landing.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LandingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(User)
        church_id = self.request.session.get('church_id', None)
        print(church_id)
        if church_id:
            samples = ObituarySample.objects.filter(organization__id=church_id)
            context['obituary_samples'] = samples

            recent_obituaries = Obituary.objects.filter(organization__id=church_id).order_by("-id")[:3]
            context['recent_obituaries'] = recent_obituaries

        context['church_cover'] = self.request.session.get('church_cover', None)
        return context
```

Comment: show your `views.py`

Comment: @shotgunner added the views.py

Comment: Can you check in your settings files. Is auth context processor added?

Comment: `user.is_authenticated` is both callable and also attribute -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Comment: @shafikur yes, auth context processor is already there

Comment: simply use this {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %} and let me know if u facing still same issue

Comment: @lakshmisaikota i tried that but still the same problem... i have run the project on my local machine it works perfectly fine.... and also works on aws ec2... but not working on this new server